# python3.3 urllib.request.urlopen cookies

Tags: python, json, httpresponse

I ahve a problem with my python script, with one url, it works fine, with the other I seem to get html code from another web page

```
url = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD"
url = "https://satoshidice.com/api/info"
```

.

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
dataread = data.readall()

datadecode = dataread.decode('utf-8')
print("datadecode:")
print(datadecode)

js = json.loads(datadecode)
print("JS:")
print(js)
```

when url = "https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD"
output:

```
datadecode:
{
  "24h_avg": 230.69,
  "ask": 244.3,
  "bid": 244.08,
  "last": 244.32,
  "timestamp": "Tue, 05 Nov 2013 15:02:33 -0000",
  "total_vol": 80993.79
}
JS:
{'total_vol': 80993.79, 'last': 244.32, 'timestamp': 'Tue, 05 Nov 2013 15:02:33 -0000', '24h_avg': 230.69, 'ask': 244.3, 'bid': 244.08}
```

when url = "https://satoshidice.com/api/info"
output:

```
datadecode:
<HTML>
<head>
<style>
<!--
body,td,div,p,a,font,span{ font-family:arial,sans-serif;}
.accent1 {background-color: #DEEFE0}
.accent2 {background-color: #006633}
-->
</style>
<title>How to Enable Cookies</title>
</head>
<body class=search bgcolor=ffffff text=000000 link=0000CC vlink=800080 alink=ff0000  topmargin=3>
<script language="JavaScript">
...
Cookies must be enabled in your browser!</font><br>
```

From the last line written in the output, I think that I'm being sent to another url because cookies aren't enabled. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for most non-trivial "browsing" from within python that you use [requests](http://www.python-requests.org). Specifically, create a [session](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects), which persists between requests, stores cookies, and so on. Just `pip install requests` and you are on your way.